# D3 bounding box in v4

Tags: d3.js, zooming, bounding-box, panning

How can we do something like this in version 4 of d3:
    http://jsfiddle.net/d3wxP/1/
because some translate or scale does not exist:

```
function move() {
```

var t = d3.event.translate,
      s = d3.event.scale;

t[0] = Math.max(0, Math.min(t[0], width - s*50));
  t[1] = Math.max(0, Math.min(t[1], height - s*50));

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + t + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it the following way:

```
function move() {
  var t = d3.event.transform,
      s = d3.event.transform.k;

  t.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(t.x, width - s*50));
  t.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(t.y, height - s*50));

  svg.attr("transform", t);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/d3wxP/18/

Documentation on that: https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom-transforms (please note that at some point it might be not backwards compatible).